# Don't refresh when login fail

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, forms

I'm creating a website for my assignment, and I want the page to not refresh after I entered the wrong password and username combination.

I'm using both PHP and javascript, and I don't use MYSQL to store the login information

This is my PHP Script

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
&& !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    if ($_POST['username'] == 'admin' && 
    $_POST['password'] == 'admin') {
    $_SESSION['username'] = 'admin';
    header ('Location: mainPage.php');
    }else {
        /*What should I include here? */
    }
}?>
```

This is my Javascript code

```
<script>function pasuser(form) {
if (form.username.value=="admin") { 
    if (form.password.value=="admin") {              
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("loginFail").innerHTML = '<div class="w3-container w3-section w3-red"> <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\'" class="w3-closebtn">×</span><h3>WRONG PASSWORD</h3><p>You need to enter the correct password.</p></div>';
    }
}
else{
    document.getElementById("loginFail").innerHTML = '<div class="w3-container w3-section w3-red"> <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\'" class="w3-closebtn">×</span><h3>WRONG USERNAME</h3><p>You need to enter the correct username.</p></div>';
}</script>
```

and the form

```
<html><form class="w3-container w3-card-8 w3-margin-16" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >

        <h2 class="w3-text-blue">LOGIN PAGE</h2>

        <p>      
        <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter your username here"></p>

        <p>      
        <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password here"></p>

        <p>      
        <button type='submit' class="w3-btn w3-blue" type="button" name="login" value="LOGIN" onclick="pasuser(form)">LOGIN</button></p>

        <span id="loginFail">

    </form></html>
```

Basically I want the javascript function of displaying a W3.CSS card alert when the login is not success without having the page reloads itself. If the page reloads itself, the card will dissapear

Comment: Why did you verify password with both JS and PHP?

Comment: I need to verify with JS because JS will show the card alert... can I run JS code ion PHP?

Comment: You cannot. Instead what you can do is get your form details and make an ajax (xhr) call to php page get the response and based on response display the proper message . Everything will be seamless. No refreshing as you asked in question.

Comment: @ZeeshanHyder unfortunately, I can't code in ajax, can you please help me :'(

Comment: @SyahnurNizam : I have posted my answer, check it. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using jQuery, here is the native code:

```
function pasuser(){
var request = new Request('login.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    body: new FormData( document.getElementById('form') ), //set id='form' to your <form> element
    mode: 'same-origin',
    redirect: 'manual',
    headers: new Headers({ 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
});
fetch(request).then(function(response){
   if(response.message == "success"){
       alert("Login Info correct!"); 
        window.location.href="home.php" // For eg.
       //Do redirect or whatever.
   }else if(response.message == "error"){
       document.querySelector('#loginFail').innerHTML = "Login Info Incorrect!"; //display error message
   }
})
}
```

And separate your php into different login.php file. Dont use PHP_SELF. It's vulnerable for XSS attacks.

`login.php`

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    if ($_POST['username'] == 'admin' && $_POST['password'] == 'admin') {
    $_SESSION['username'] = 'admin';

    $res = array("message"=>"success");
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo (json_encode($res));
    }else {
        $res = array("message"=>"error");
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        echo(json_encode($res));
    }
  }
?>
```